Can I find loaded but unsent Line app picture in temporary files?
My friend sent me a picture in the Line app and I opened it already and it loaded to the screen (download to screen), but I didn't save it to my phone with the Line app so I cannot see it in Gallery.
Then he unsent that picture.
Can I still find this picture because my Line has downloaded/loaded it 100% to my screen?

Probably not...
